# Jquery sortable elements allocate on drag and drop

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to implement jquery's sortable in my website, but it has wierd behavioir.When i try to drag element to another position, other elements seem to allocate so i was wondering if anyone can explain to me why is this happening?

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="sortable"> 
  <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/plugins/htmlcodetutorial-plugin/assets/images/firefox-true.png" height="100px" width="100px" class="ui-state-default">
  <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/plugins/htmlcodetutorial-plugin/assets/images/firefox-true.png" height="100px" width="100px" class="ui-state-default">
  <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/plugins/htmlcodetutorial-plugin/assets/images/firefox-true.png" height="100px" width="100px" class="ui-state-default">
  <img src="https://html.com/wp-content/plugins/htmlcodetutorial-plugin/assets/images/firefox-true.png" height="100px" width="100px" class="ui-state-default">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove width and height from the images and 
use additionally this css:

```
#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 450px;
}

#sortable img {
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

look at this:
https://jsfiddle.net/r1tzswkL/6/